# Installing from via terminal (YUM) vs using GUI with dependencies

Tags: linux, terminal, rhel, yum, dependencies

Hello I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.2, I'm having issue installing package in via terminal.

I already have packages in specific folder including the dependencies.
For example, when i try this command.
example:

```
yum install package.1.0.1.el6.i686.rpm
```

It will output something like this:

```
Error: Package: package.1.0.1.el6.i686.rpm
Requires: libpackage1.1.1.el6.i686.rpm
```

The packages required packages was already in the same folder. When I try using GUI it successfully installing with the dependencies required. I'm just trying to practice installing via terminal so some servers don't use GUI.

Thanks

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how to automatically install the dependencies in yum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum` will not automatically look in the local directory for dependencies - it will look at it's configured repositories to resolve dependencies. Is there a reason you can't use the standard repositories and pull dependencies from the network?

If you do have a complete set of dependencies, you can use `rpm --aid` to install a package and dependencies from a local directory, or you can play around with `yum localinstall` if that functionality hasn't been deprecated.

Comment: So in other word I need to install all dependencies manually?

Comment: No. `yum` should take care of dependencies for you without you having to download them, if you're using the Red Hat repositories. `rpm --aid` will try to pick up the dependencies it needs from the local working directory and install them for you.